# How can I get the QStyleOptionSpinBox to render the model value?

Tags: delegates, pyqt6

I am trying to create a column for a spin box delegate. Although I have the behaviour so that I can edit data and update the model, I cannot print the current model value into the cell. Unlike other options I cannot find a "text", or "value" field into the QStyleOptionSpinBox. Thus, all I see is an empty cell with the up and down arrows. I don't see any fields to set a value on the API.

This is my working implementation so far,

```
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView, QStyledItemDelegate, QSpinBox, QStyleOptionSpinBox, QStyle
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt


class SpinBoxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        spinBoxOption = QStyleOptionSpinBox()
        spinBoxOption.palette = option.palette
        spinBoxOption.state = option.state
        spinBoxOption.rect = option.rect
        QApplication.style().drawComplexControl(QStyle.ComplexControl.CC_SpinBox, spinBoxOption, painter)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QSpinBox(parent)
        editor.setMinimum(-100)
        editor.setMaximum(100)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.model().data(index, Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole)
        editor.setValue(int(value))

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = editor.value()
        model.setData(index, value, Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole)


app = QApplication([])

model = QStandardItemModel(4, 1)
tableView = QTableView()
tableView.setModel(model)

for row in range(4):
    column = 0
    item = QStandardItem()
    item.setData((row + 1) * 25, Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
    model.setItem(row, column, item)


tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, SpinBoxDelegate())
tableView.show()

app.exec()
```

How can I get each cell to display the current model values when not editing?

Comment: That's because QSpinBoxes don't draw the value, their embedded [`lineEdit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractspinbox.html#lineEdit) does. Besides, I see little use in drawing the same control as in the editor, just keep the editor open using [`openPersistentEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#openPersistentEditor).

Comment: @musicamante but the lineEdit() is only accessed inside the createEditor. How can I get it to render it during the paint method?

Comment: You would need the related QStyleOptionFrame and fill everything related to its shape, style and, most importantly, text appearance, which is quite complex if you want to keep look consistent. That's why I won't suggest that and, as said, I propose you to just keep the editor persistently open.